# Python help working with packages and modules

Tags: python, package, python-module, python-packaging

I need some help with working with a folder structure in python. I was given an structure like this:

```
/main-folder
    /assets
        somefiles.txt
    /integrations
        /module-folder
            __init__.py
            ingestion.py
        __init__.py
    models.py
```

Inside *ingestion.py* I have:

```
import os    
from models import MyModel

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

some_function()
    some_processing()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_function()
```

Both `__init__.py` mentioned above are empty.

So I need to process some info and use the `models` module to store them. when trying to execute `intestion.py` directly from its dir it says: `No module named 'models'`. So I'm guessing I have to execute the whole thing as a package. I have no idea how should I import a module located above the package and can't touch the structure.

Any help woud be appreciated.

Comment: If you try to execute it from `main-folder`, it should work. ie; `python ./integrations/module-folder/ingestion.py`.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to add the module's directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. If you don't want to do this however, You can modify the sys.path list in your program where the Python interpreter searches for the modules to import, the python documentation [says](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:

- the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
- the installation-dependent default.

After initialization, Python programs can modify sys.path. The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the replacement is intended.

Knowing this, you can do the following in your program:

```
import sys
# Add the main-folder folder path to the sys.path list
sys.path.append('/path/to/main-folder/')

# Now you can import your module
from main-folder import models
# Or just
import main-folder
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It can be overwhelming to look for the correct piece of information, so having someone with the experience its a relief. I ended up appending my main-folder dir to the PYTHONPATH environmental variable: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/absolute/path/to/main-folder`

Comment: In my mind, it is the wrong way to go about it. There is almost never an actual need to modify `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`. There is almost always a better way to solve such issues. I would start by starting the program by calling it as an [_executable module_](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) instead of a _script_: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m integrations.module_folder.ingestion`.